# Creating and Exporting Excel files in R based on nested Categories in two Columns

Tags: r, data-analysis

R useRs,
I've a data set that includes different states, and each state has a number of banks and their rating scores. From the excel data file, I want to:

1. create a separate folder for each state of the States column,
   and 2) export each bank in a separate excel file inside its own state.

Here is simulated data for explanation:

```
States = rep(c("AR", "KS", "CA", "MO", "NE"),times = c(10, 5, 15, 8, 12))
Banks = c(paste0("Bank_", 1:50))
Rating = rnorm(50, mean=30, sd=5)
MyData = data.frame(States, Banks, Rating)
```

I always use the function of `dir.create("MyFolder")` to create folders, and use Map `myList = split(df, df$States) Map(openxlsx::write.xlsx, myList, paste0(names(myList), '.xlsx'))`
to export excel files, but I so not know how to combine these.

The result should include five different folders, each folder should be named based on the name of the state, and each state folder should include the banks that are located in the state, and the name of the excel file should be based on the "Banks" column. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, using `purrr`

```
 MyData %>% 
  nest(-States,-Banks) %>% 
  pwalk(
      .f = function(States,data,Banks){
        dir.create(States)
        openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = data, file = file.path(getwd(),States,paste0(Banks,".xlsx")))
    })
```

### Results

```
list.files(full.names = T,include.dirs = T)

"./AR" "./CA" "./KS" "./MO" "./NE"

list.files(path = file.path(getwd(),"AR"))

 [1] "Bank_1.xlsx"  "Bank_10.xlsx" "Bank_2.xlsx"  "Bank_3.xlsx"  "Bank_4.xlsx"  "Bank_5.xlsx" 
 [7] "Bank_6.xlsx"  "Bank_7.xlsx"  "Bank_8.xlsx"  "Bank_9.xlsx"
```

Comment: Thank you, @Vinícius Félix, I really appreciate your help, but this code does not export each bank in its own excel file - each file should be named by the name of the bank. How can I do so?

Comment: That's strange, here the data is exported like `"./MO/MO.xlsx"` is that the desired output?

Comment: Exporting the folders with the names of the state was perfect. But each folder includes one excel file that has the same name of the folder with all of the banks included in it. What I still need help with is to export each bank (one row) as excel file, this excel file should be named as the name of the bank inside its own state.

Comment: Sorry @Identicon I missread your question, I think now will attend